# my nested if statement, need to make an uninterruptible condition

Tags: c, if-statement, nested-loops

I've been trying to program an Radio Control car to follow a line depending on the readings of five line-following sensors.

The line-following sensors give 1 when they are on the line and 0 when they are not.

For example: If the sensors reads 00100, the car will go forward.

I faced a problem, when the sensors read 11111 (dead end).

- The car should make a uturn. While it is doing the uturn the condition of the sensors change.

  - Say it becomes 11000.
- That new value takes me to another if statement which is if 11000 turn left and the uturn order is lost.

**Question:** How can I make the if statement for uturn uninterruptible by other if statements when the condition changes?

Comment: Get some better sensors, or algorithm. If 00100 from 5 sensors means the car can go forwards, surely 11111 means the car can go in any direction.

Comment: I have made 17 if statement to cover EVERY possible situation. but what I need to know is when my car makes a uturn it gets interrupted by one of the if statements because the condition of the sensors change. how can I stop that?

Comment: If you have 5 binary states and they're independent, you need 32 cases in total (2⁵ = 32).  Therefore, unless some of your 17 tests cover more than one case, you haven't got enough tests.

Comment: I have made a truth table for the 32 possible situations and then i took out the impossible situations. like 10011 or 11011 since its only 1 line on the ground or a horizontal line (11111)

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean.

```
if (sensors == "11111") makingUturn = true
```

then

```
if (sensors == "00100") makingUturn = false
```

Now for all other conditions, check if `makingUturn` is false before continuing with the code for that condition

#### Note

In case it wasn't obvious, this wasn't meant as actual code to compile and execute. What I mean by `if (sensors == "ddddd")`, is to check that all 5 sensors have the value at each position of the string. And when I say `makingUturn = bool` is to replace the bool with a 1 or 0 depending on if you want `true` or `false`

Comment: u mean like I set uturn as a Boolean variable, set it true when I want my car to make a uturn and set it false everywhere else?

Comment: @Jood you don't set it to false everywhere else. You only set it to false when the car is going forward i.e. `00100` as you said in your question. You then set it to true when your sensors read `11111`, i.e. when it is time to make a uturn. Since a u-turn means a 180 degree rotation, then the only way to go after the car completes this turn is forward and your sensors should read `00100` at this point, and then this is when the boolean will be set to false